# Missing commands in MySQL command line history

Tags: mysql, mac-os-x, command-line

Why aren't all command that are entered in the MySQL command line saved in the command history?

For example, entering the commands

```
DROP DATABASE mydb;
CREATE DATABASE mydb DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
GRANT ALL ON mydb.* TO username@host IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

and then trying to go through the history by pressing   <kbd>▲</kbd>   I only see the first two commands.

---

I'm running MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for osx10.12 (x86_64) installed with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

Comment: I suppose is to keep safe admin information, like usernames and passwords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an option to prevent some commands that contain specific words from being logged. One common practice is not to log commands that has the word `password`.

This option is called `histignore`

More info:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_histignore
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-logging.html